# Stop the itemtap event when I tap in a button which is inside the item list, and keep the itemtap event if I press anywhere outside the button

Tags: sencha-touch-2

if I press the decline button it should removes the item from the list, but if I press the area around the button I should see the office detail

[image: see the screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to include the  event.stopEvent() inside the button tap handler. that is it. :)

```
declineRequestButtonTap: function (self,event) {
  console.log('decline button tap functionality'); //your code 
  event.stopEvent(); //this stops the itemtap event  
},
onRequestItemTap: function (list, idx, el, record) {
  console.log('I didn't press the button I pressed anywhere out of the button but inside the item list.') //your code 
},
```

or if you have the  listener inside the view

```
    xtype: 'button',
    flex: 1,
    text: 'decline',
    ui: 'decline',
    listeners: {
      tap: function (self,event) {
        //your code 
        event.stopEvent();
      }
```